# How to know how much network bandwidth a web application needs?

Tags: asp.net, bandwidth

My customer ask  our Web Application's bandwidth requirement. The website will be hosted on customer server. How can I know exactly how much network bandwidth it requires? It is used to manage company data, no audio/video transferring.

Comment: Is it a audio/video thing? The general way is to have an estimate of the amount of data that will flow through per second and generalize it to a per day estimate

Comment: It has no audio/video. How can I estimate the amount of data that will flow per second? Open Browser Developer tool then measure the request size? Is there a tool to help me measure this value?

Comment: That's one way but in general you should have a sense of what your app does and how big the payloads coming in and going out are? No? Or just run it for a couple of days and see the average usage

Comment: Can you suggest me the formula to calculate the bandwidth?

Comment: If you are doing 100 requests a second. Each request moves 1kb of data. Then you are shuffling 100kb of data per second. Multiply by 86400 to get how much data moved in a day. The important part is having some estimate of how many bytes of data is being moved per request or per second. Everyone starts from an estimate